# cant create stored procedure using type varchar 2-pls-00103

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

i have tried to create a stored procedure using  sql developer and oracle database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_CATALOG 
  (COUNTRY IN NOCOPY CATALOG.COUNTRY%TYPE)
AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CATALOG (COUN_ID, COUNTRY) 
    VALUES (COUN_ID_SEQ.nextval , COUNTRY);
  COMMIT;
END INSERT_CATALOG;
```

and i was recevingthis kind error on compiling

**Error**

> Error(3,19): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CATALOG" when expecting one of the following:     := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for "CATALOG" to continue.

Please help with this code

Comment: I have tried it too but no changes in it same error@D-Shih

Comment: Can you show the schema from `CATALOG` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `NOCOPY`.

It can be used with `OUT` or `IN OUT` parameters, but not with `IN`.